# SOAP web service uri or namespace format

Tags: python, perl, web-services, soap

So I have seen SOAP client programs with `namespace` and `url` for python

and using `uri` and `proxy` for perl such as below

python [soap client](http://www.cwroethel.com/Articles/SOAPQuick/SOAP-QuickPython.htm):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from SOAPpy import SOAPProxy

option = sys.argv[1]

serverUrl='http://localhost:9000'
namespace='urn:/Date'
server = SOAPProxy(serverUrl, namespace)
response = server.dateInfo(option)

# read out the response
if (response == None):
    print "Call returned error."
    sys.exit(1)

print "Currently server date and time is " + response
```

perl [soap client](http://guide.soaplite.com/#writing%20a%20client):

```
  #!perl -w
  use SOAP::Lite;
  $soap_response = SOAP::Lite
    -> uri('http://www.soaplite.com/Demo')
    -> proxy('http://services.soaplite.com/hibye.cgi')
    -> languages();
  @res = $soap_response->paramsout;
  $res = $soap_response->result;                               
  print "Result is $res, outparams are @res\n";
```

Now here in first, namespace is `urn:/Date` 
and in second program uri is `http://www.soaplite.com/Demo`.

I know that `uri` and `namespace` are words used to represent the same i.e. namespace used by SOAP to register a service.

My question is that whether the format used to name it 
i.e. `urn:...` or `http://...` mandatory 
or can I simply use something like `testwebservice` to register web service

Answer (score 0):

The namespace name is an absolute IRI. (An IRI is basically an URI with support for non-ASCII characters.) Any absolute IRI. The scheme (http, urn, etc) doesn't matter. It can't be `testwebservice` since that's not a valid absolute IRI (or URI).

The namespace name is only used for identification purposes. It isn't used for resource retrieval, so using an HTTP IRI that would return 404 is perfectly fine.